# MySQL 5.7 low performance with GROUP BY or DATETIME columns

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySQL 5.7 almost always and I never had performances issues.
But the project I'm working on lately is realy making me doubt about MySQL.

This project in the last year generated a pretty huge DB with tables sometime with 15mln records.
I'm thinking about partitioning but I need to get rid of foreign keys so this is all another problem that I'll probably discuss here in the next future with you guys.

So techinically my staff and I are trying to optmize all the tables, indexes and queries in order to perform.

What I've been taught since I was a student is "let do the database what the database is capable of doing" and that's always been my creed.

First of I noticed that MySQL does not perform with datetime columns in the right way. The first optimization was to convert all the datetime columns into integer values (converting datetime into int timestamp values) and with this little modification and by indexing those columns I decreased significantly the amount of time to get the same result.

Moreover I noticed that with some queries using the "GROUP BY" inside a query or doing a group using the programming language in charge to elaborate results the database is significantly slower.

So first datetime columns (maybe treated like strings don't allows MySQL core to perform) and in second place the "GROUP BY" which I think is one of the most used command.

I'm starting thinking that probably what's wrong here is MySQL tuning so here I share my configuration file (my.cnf):

```
symbolic-links=0
query_cache_size = 32M
thread_cache_size = 8
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
table_open_cache = 512
max_allowed_packet = 1M
key_buffer_size = 384M

sql-mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

max_allowed_packet = 32M
max_connections = 2000
open_files_limit = 10000
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
tmpdir = /home/mysql/tmp
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
skip_name_resolve
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0
log_bin
server_id = 1
max_binlog_size = 100M
expire_logs_days = 7
sync_binlog = 0
binlog_format = MIXED
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 26G
innodb_log_file_size = 3GB
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
#innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown = 1
#innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct = 75
innodb_adaptive_hash_index = ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts = 16
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0
innodb_page_cleaners = 8
long_query_time = 4
slow_query_log = 1
```

So as you can see I talked about simple query operations such "GROUP BY" and DATETIME columns, that's why I probabily think the problem is related to MySQL tuning.
I'm also thinking about migrating to MySQL 8.0 but I need to try this database on a test machine before going on a production environment.

I don't know where I can hit my head to get a solution.

Comment: Generally, the important things are the queries, and the table structures ; so the things you seem unwilling to share

Comment: `PARTITIONing` rarely improves performance.  I _must_ see more details to provide you with more details.

Comment: @RickJames please tell me what kind of details you are going to need and I'll be more than glad to provide eveything...

Comment: @prelite - `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; the proposed partitioning; a few of the 'common' or 'slow' queries.